# Follow up question to what is the $2006^{\text{th}}$ term in the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a sequence of integers, $t_1, t_2, \ldots; t_{n+3} = t_n+t_{n+1}-t_{n+2}$ for $n \geq 1$. If the first three terms, in order, are $1$, $3$, and $6$, what is the $2006^{\text{th}}$ term?

There was an answer to my question which said that $t_{2n+1} = 1+5n$ and $t_{2n} = 8-5n$. I want to prove this by induction and what I have so far is this:

Assume that $t_{2k} = 8-5k$. Then by the formula we have that $t_{2(k+1)} = t_{2k-1}+t_{2k}+t_{2k+1}$. What do I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can do an induction over the odd numbers.  You have $t_{2n+1}=1+5n$ for $n=0,1$.  Assume $t_{2k+1}=1+5k$.  Then $t_{2k+3}=t_{2k}+t_{2k+1}-t_{2k+2}=8-5k+1+5k-(8-5(k+2))=1+5(k+1)$

Comment: So we assume both equations are true then show it holds for both?

Comment: You said you had already proven the even case.  I accepted that and proved the odd case.  It is a good test of your understanding of induction. One way is to prove the evens by induction, then for each odd assume all the evens are proved already. Another way is to assume for each $n$ you have already proved the smaller $n$, even though you have different equations for odd and even $n$.  Which way works depends on the equations you have.  One way is proving $0,2,4,6,\dots , 1,3,5 \dots$ and the other is proving $0,1,2,3,4,5 \dots $.  Both ways get you all the naturals.  For the first, you need

Comment: both $0$ and $1$ as base cases.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to prove the even case, but I think it works to assume it holds for both even and odd subscripts then proceed with induction.

Comment: You need a little care. Induction is a formalization of the method of infinite descent.  If there is one solution, there is a smaller one, and there is no infinite descending chain in the naturals.  You can prove all the evens first, then assume that to prove the odds.  Or, you can prove each number assuming the lower ones have already been proven.

Comment: How do you prove just the evens using induction?